# How to have a video take up the viewport height and width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have my site play a video which takes up the full viewport. Not 100% of the body, just the viewport. So you can scroll down and view other content. Similar to how mediaboom.com does it.

I've managed to make the video take up the full viewport (and no more), which is what I'm aiming for. But it's not responsive. Meaning the video should remain centered when the window is resized. But it gets cut off.

Here's what I have for the html so far:

```
<div id="featured">
        <video poster="assets/poster.jpg" autoplay="true" muted="true" loop>
            <source src="assets/home.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
body, html {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#featured {

max-height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}


video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the `object-fit: contain/cover`, this one work on IE/Edge as well

*As mentioned in a comment, to mimic `contain` use `max-width/max-height` instead.*
*Also note, the sample video takes a few seconds to load*

Sample that mimic `object-fit: cover`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#featured {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100vh * (1000 / 562));    /*  video width / height  */
  height: calc(100vw * (562 / 1000));   /*  video height / width  */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="featured">
    <video poster="assets/poster.jpg" autoplay="true" muted="true" loop>
      <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sample using `object-fit`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#featured {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* or contain */
}
```

```html
<div id="featured">
  <video poster="assets/poster.jpg" autoplay="true" muted="true" loop>
      <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The video takes up the full viewport height but not the width. Using max-height: 100vh for the featured div works. But the video doesn't take up the full viewport height for smaller screens. I need it to bleed out video from the sides and keep it centered always.

Comment: @RashedDoha: So how should the video get cropped/stretched when its aspect ratio doesn't match the viewports aspect ratio?

Comment: Yes the video will get cropped. But equally from all sides. So the cropped portion that you see, will always be the center part that fits within the dimensions (100% width and 100vh).

EDIT: I just noticed your edited version and in this case the video doesn't take 100% of the width. object-fit: cover seems to do the trick though.

Comment: @RashedDoha updated my answer with a cross browser solution

Comment: It works!! Amazing, this is exactly what I was asking for. And it works on Edge and IE as well. Thank a lot. But can you explain how you calculated the width and height? Do the values 1000 and 562 need to be replaced by the video's actual width and height?

Comment: @RashedDoha The 1000 and 562 was the size I got when inspected the dummy video I used. You should use your video's width and height instead, as that value is needed to get (and keep) the video's aspect ratio.

Comment: Yeah of course, sorry about that. I seem to forget. Thanks again!

Comment: A tip for anyone who wants the video to never be cropped: Change `min-width` and `min-height` to `max-width` and `max-height`.

Comment: @makeworld -- Thanks, correct, updated my answer with that

Comment: @Ason it still says `min` instead of `max` in both places.

Comment: @makeworld -- Yes, the sample still use `min-*`, and it does that as that was what was asked for, but I added a note saying that if one want the video to be _`contain`ed_ instead of _`cover`ing_, one can use `max-*`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use object-fit: cover in your CSS, only catch is that there is no IE support. It's effectively the same as background-size: cover, though!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Ah yes, that works perfectly. I knew about object-fit but didn't realize it could solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly, but I tried your code changing min-width:100%; and min-height:100%; for width:100%; and height:100%; and the window resizes correctly.

EDIT:

I am sorry but I don't know where to look in mediaboom.com there is a lot of stuff there.

But if you want:

- To keep aspect ratio of the video.
- Have the video as tall as the viewport lets you.
- Crop the width of the video if necessary, but keep the video centered
- Add more elements under the video div which you can reach by scrolling

Then try with this. If it isn't the solution it might get you closer:

```
body, html {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #featured {
            width: 100wh;
            height: 100vh;
            position: relative;
        }


        video {
            width:100wh;
            height: 100Vh;
            display:inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            margin-right: -50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }
```

Comment: Yes it resizes but I need the image to always take up the viewport height. When you resize the browser in your case it maintains the aspect ratio by shrinking the height along with the width. But it should crop the width, and keep the height constant at 100vh. Check out mediaboom.com for reference.